# PostgreSQL: Conditional INSERT INTO on some of multiple columns from difference tables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Please, I am a newbie in PostgreSQL/PLPGSQL and I have tried to search on SO here and there on Google, but could not find specific solutions. I do apologies if this question is duplicated.

I want to create trigger function(s) that can insert values from table_main and if other sub-tables have values, a custom string (link) will be inserted into the same row in line with data from table_main.

I have 3 tables which auto-generated by an application, which are similar to:

-- table_main

```
CREATE TABLE table_main
(
  main_a character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  main_b character varying(255),
  main_c character varying(255),
  main_d character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT main_a_pkey UNIQUE (main_a)
);
```

-- table_sub1

```
CREATE TABLE table_sub1
(
  sub_a character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  sub_b character varying(255),
  sub_c character varying(255),
  sub_d character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT table_sub1_pkey UNIQUE (sub_a)
);
```

-- table_sub2

```
CREATE TABLE table_sub2
(
  sub2_a character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  sub2_b character varying(255),
  sub2_c character varying(255),
  sub2_d character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT table_sub2_pkey UNIQUE (sub2_a)
);
```

Also, I have another table to store data to be copied from table_main and custom strings (links), as below:

-- table_copy

```
CREATE TABLE table_copy
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  copy_a character varying(80),
  copy_b character varying(255),
  copy_c character varying(255),
  copy_d character varying(255),
  copy_e character varying(255),
  copy_f character varying(255),
  copy_g character varying(255)
);
```

My purpose is to:

1. Copy data from table_main to table_copy when a record is inserted into table_main, using below trigger function, and it works fine:

.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_data()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_copy (
copy_a,
copy_b,
copy_c,
copy_d)
VALUES ( 
NEW."main_a", 
NEW."main_b",
NEW."main_c",
NEW."main_d"
);
RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION save_data() OWNER TO postgres;
DROP TRIGGER trigger_save_data ON "table_main";
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_save_data BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON "table_main" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_data();
```

Check and result:

```
smart=# INSERT INTO table_main (main_a, main_b, main_c, main_d) VALUES ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
INSERT 0 1
smart=# SELECT * FROM table_copy;
 id | copy_a | copy_b | copy_c | copy_d | copy_e | copy_f | copy_g
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
  3 | aaa    | bbb    | ccc    | ddd    |        |        |
(1 row)
```

2. My second (and more important) purpose is to insert custom strings into some last columns in table_copy (in the same row, of course) with conditions based on `table_sub1` and `table_sub2`, e.g, IF `table_sub1.sub_c` or `table_sub2.sub2_d` have values inserted, the custom strings (links) to be inserted into `table_copy.copy_e` or `table_copy.copy_f`, respectively.

I have tried some solutions below but all do not satisfy me.

Solution 1: Set each trigger on each table of `table_main`, `table_sub1` and `table_sub2`. Result: It creates three rows in `table_copy` ==> not accepted.

Trigger on `table_sub1:`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_data_sub1()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_copy (copy_e) VALUES ('link_to_sub1_here');
RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION save_data_sub1() OWNER TO postgres;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_save_data_sub1 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON "table_sub1" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_data_sub1();
```

Trigger on `table_sub2:`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_data_sub2()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_copy (copy_f) VALUES ('link_to_sub2_here');
RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION save_data_sub2() OWNER TO postgres;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_save_data_sub1 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON "table_sub2" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_data_sub2();
```

Test and results (with all 3 triggers above):

```
smart=# INSERT INTO table_sub1 VALUES ('abc', 'bca', 'aaa', 'cba');
INSERT 0 1
smart=# INSERT INTO table_sub2 VALUES ('cvb', 'bvc', 'aaa', 'vcb');
INSERT 0 1
smart=# SELECT * FROM table_copy;
 id | copy_a | copy_b | copy_c | copy_d |      copy_e       |      copy_f       | copy_g
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+--------
  6 | aaa    | bbb    | ccc    | ddd    |                   |                   |
  7 |        |        |        |        | link_to_sub1_here |                   |
  8 |        |        |        |        |                   | link_to_sub2_here |
(3 rows)


smart=#
```

Solution 2: Using `IF EXISTS (SELECT........ WHERE) THEN INSERT INTO table_copy (copy_e) VALUES ('a link here') END IF;` right below `RETURN NEW;` in the trigger function `save_data()` above, it is still resulted new rows. ==> not accepted also.

Solution 3: Using the same IF EXISTS ...... THEN .... above, ==> ERROR.

What I want is, the data is inserted into one row (6), not being generated to three rows. Here is my expectation:

```
 id | copy_a | copy_b | copy_c | copy_d |      copy_e       |      copy_f       | copy_g
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+--------
  6 | aaa    | bbb    | ccc    | ddd    | link_to_sub1_here | link_to_sub2_here |
```

As said above, I am newbie and could not find solutions to make my dream come true. Please, any expert here can give me a light.

Comment: can you show us some sample data with the inserts sequence and the result you expect to get. Your question is good but there is room for improvement, please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: Thank you very much for your prompt feedback. I've updated my question. Please help.

Comment: What you are missing on your functions is the link between the registries on the table_main and table_sub1 and 2. In order to your solution work properly it should somehow now the ID (os some identifiable column) to change on table_copy otherwise you get your problem, you have inserts where it should be updates on the functions save_data_sub1() and save_data_sub2()

Comment: @Jorge Campos: Thank you very much. However, your suggestion is very new for me. Could you please give me further detail on this matter, or give me some examples with links, so I can learn.

Comment: There is no information how rows in `table_main` and `table_sub1` etc. are connected. Typically, you would have [foreign keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) of some sort (formally declared or not). There is also no information about the order in which rows are entered into each table, no information about possible updates or concurrent access. The question cannot be answered in its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all here for your suggestions and comments. Finally I got it work with below solution.

Since the `table_main.main_a` column is `pkey` of `table_main`, and there is one (not `pkey` or `fkey`) column in each `table_sub1` and `table_sub2` have the same value with `table_main.main_a`. In addition, values (if any) come to `table_sub1` and `table_sub2` **first**, then come to `table_main` (always). So, my trigger function below works, perfectly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_data()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_copy (
copy_a,
copy_b,
copy_c,
copy_d)
VALUES ( 
NEW."main_a", 
NEW."main_b",
NEW."main_c",
NEW."main_d"
);
--Since value in table_sub1.sub_c is the same value in table_main.main_a
PERFORM sub_c FROM table_sub1 WHERE sub_c = NEW.main_a;
IF FOUND THEN UPDATE table_copy SET copy_e = ('link_to_sub1_here');
END IF;
--Since value in table_sub2.sub2_c is also the same value in table_main.main_a
PERFORM sub2_c FROM table_sub2 WHERE sub2_c = NEW.main_a;
IF FOUND THEN UPDATE table_copy SET copy_f = ('link_to_sub2_here');
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION save_data() OWNER TO postgres;
DROP TRIGGER trigger_save_data ON "table_main";
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_save_data BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON "table_main" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_data();
```

And here is test result:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO table_sub2 VALUES ('cdef', 'abv', 'abcde', 'a12');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO table_sub1 VALUES ('cdeb', 'abv', 'abcde', 'a12');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO table_main (main_a, main_b, main_c, main_d) VALUES ('abcde', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# SELECT * FROM table_copy;
 id | copy_a | copy_b | copy_c | copy_d |      copy_e       |      copy_f       | copy_g
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+--------
  6 | abcde  | bbb    | ccc    | ddd    | link_to_sub1_here | link_to_sub2_here |
(1 row)


postgres=#
```

Just provide solution for someone needed.

Cheers.